# How to format date on FullCalendar on that way, when I click on event?

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

How to format date on FullCalendar on that way, when I click on event? (for example) and use this code:

```
  eventClick: function( calEvent, jsEvent, view ){
    alert('start: ' + calEvent.start);
    alert('end: ' + calEvent.end);
  },
```

that alert show something like

```
start: 12/28/2013 14:55   
end: 12/28/2013 18:55
```

instead of `"Tue Dec 28 2013 ... "`

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since fullcalendars' event start and end properties are javascript `Date` objects, it is responsibility of the code that displays them to handle their formatting, they don't have a specific format by themselves.

The easiest way I found to handle dates in javascript is to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Formatting your date in your alert would then be something like

```
alert('start: ' + moment(calEvent.start).format('DD/MM/YYYYhh:mm'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update: This answer provides a solution for version 1 of FullCalendar. From version 2 Moment.js is used by FullCalendar, and this answer is not longer valid**

Moment.js is a really great library, but you could also use the `formatDate()` function provided by FullCalendar if you don't want to add another dependency.

It works like this:

```
alert('start: ' + 
     $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'));
```

You can check out the documentation for `formatDate()` here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/utilities/formatDate/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me;
var startDate =$.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('YYYY/MM/DD');

Comment: Format code as code by indenting 4 spaces. Might be also worth explaining why you believe this will fix the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
var startFix= moment($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```