# how do get the date of an event into a date object in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

i want the .getDate() code to return a date object so that i can compare it to an array of date objects. i know i can use calEvent.start.format to get hours and what not, but that isn't working to compare to date objects.

```
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1, maxDate: "+1Y" });

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                weekends:false,
                defaultView:'agendaWeek',
                header: {
                    left:'prev,today,next',
                    center:'title',
                    right:'month,agendaWeek'
                },
                eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
                    alert('clicked on: ' + calEvent.start.getDate());
                },
            });
        });
```

Comment: How you are comparing dates? What result return calEvent.start.getDate()?

Comment: using get date doesn't work at all. that's mostly in there for help as to what i'm attempting. calEvent.start can be found here http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
i've found many stackoverflow posts that show how to use calEvent.start.format(insert desired format), but this isn't a date object.
@daremachine

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) from version **2+**. If you want to get date in desired format then you can use MomentJS API because `calEvent.start` return Moment object like documentation says

> Instead of native Date objects, Moment objects are now used throughout
>   the API.

or if you want to setup the date you should also use MomentJS API as documentation says

> start: A Moment-ish input, like an ISO8601 string. Throughout the API this
>   will become a real Moment object.

Useful sources
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/
http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/
[How to format date on FullCalendar on that way, when I click on event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141261/how-to-format-date-on-fullcalendar-on-that-way-when-i-click-on-event)

Comment: so, i already saw that documentation. I suppose the question then boils down to converting from a moment object to a date object. Are you saying that isn't possible?

Comment: @Rick sorry I don't understand you correctly. What is your question? I thought you are asking for a date format. Why you need use dateObject instead of moment object? If it is for comparing dates so you should re-think how you convert date time to the moment and compare them then trying modifying `calEv.start` to date object. Or compare values instead of whole objects.